# Including LaTeX packages in xaringan presentation?

Tags: r-markdown, xaringan

I'm trying to use the `bm` package in a xaringan presentation, but for the life of me can't figure it out. I've tried using the `header-includes` option in the YAML to no avail. Is there something very obvious I'm missing? I couldn't find anything on stackoverflow or in xaringan documentation but it's always possible I overlooked something!

Comment: `xaringan`  "is an R Markdown extension based on the JavaScript library remark.js (https://remarkjs.com) to generate HTML5 presentations of a different style". See https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/xaringan.html. Hence I'm afraid you can't use any Latex in xaringan.

Comment: I don't have an answer to the original question @stefan's answer isn't quite correct--you can definitely use LaTeX in xaringan.

Comment: Wondering if someone have already found a way to embed latex packages in xaringan.